# Parametrization of intersection of curves

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, curves, parametrization

If one wants to parametrize the curve of intersection in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of the surfaces $y=x^2$ and $z=x^3$, would it be correct to parametrize this curve as $\bf{g}$$(t)=(t, t^2,t^3)$?

The reason I'm asking this is because sometimes there are subtle errors in what we think should be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your parametrization is correct. The first surface could be parametrized by ${\bf x}(u,v) = (u, u^2, v)$. If we're in the intersection, we must have $v = u^3$. So the curve only has one parameter now, which I'll call $t$, resulting in $(t,t^2,t^3)$.